# Vega-lite Line chart order of x axis

Tags: vega, vega-lite

My data:

`(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {index: 0, month: "Jan", yield: 1.1864614990387585, Symbol(vega_id): 1}1: {index: 1, month: "Feb", yield: 2.1219813590422714, Symbol(vega_id): 2}2: {index: 2, month: "Maa", yield: 4.074651725158576, Symbol(vega_id): 3}3: {index: 3, month: "Apr", yield: 6.097184505206099, Symbol(vega_id): 4}4: {index: 4, month: "Mei", yield: 6.433726592798336, Symbol(vega_id): 5}5: {index: 5, month: "Jun", yield: 6.66769562709039, Symbol(vega_id): 6}6: {index: 6, month: "Jul", yield: 6.483542378096409, Symbol(vega_id): 7}7: {index: 7, month: "Aug", yield: 5.7479008300368495, Symbol(vega_id): 8}8: {index: 8, month: "Sep", yield: 4.3635099156150075, Symbol(vega_id): 9}9: {index: 9, month: "Okt", yield: 2.4647144833082195, Symbol(vega_id): 10}10: {index: 10, month: "Nov", yield: 1.1705485181998911, Symbol(vega_id): 11}11: {index: 11, month: "Dec", yield: 0.8511712929997286, Symbol(vega_id): 12}length: 12__proto__: Array(0)`

I need to just have them in order, but when I select 'month' as the field for the encoding.x, I get them alphabetically. When I add `sort:null`, the line still goes from Apr to Aug to Dec and so on, while the axis is in the correct order (a jumble ensues). When I select 'index' as the field for the encoding.x, I get the correct graph that I need, but I want the labels to be the months, not the index.

Comment: Check out the sort docs: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html#sorting-discrete-scales

Comment: @dominik's suggestion seems sound, in this case you could use  "sort": {"op": "min", "field": "index"} for your x field definition.  any "op" from min, max, mean, etc. would work since you would just have one value for the field for that month.